# How to check for duplicate value in database when importing vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
            For i As Integer = 0 To dgclassinfo.Rows.Count - 1

                LRN = dgclassinfo.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString
                Lname = dgclassinfo.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString
                Fname = dgclassinfo.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString
                Mname = dgclassinfo.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value.ToString


                comm.CommandText = "insert into g7(LRN,Lname,Fname,Mname ) values('" & LRN & "','" & Lname & "','" & Fname & "','" & Mname & "')"
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery()



            Next
```

I used to code above to import my data. Using dgv. My data is databound. for additional info. When I import the file it reads the value of the excel and displays in the dgv in which i insert the data using the for loop above. I think I need to use mydr.hasrows but I have no idea on how to do this using for loop. How can I check for duplicate records every row? LRN is my pk.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If your DGV is bound to a DataSource, there is no need to pull data out of it to insert. Creating SQL that way is a very bad way to do it.  Use SQL parameters always.  Checking for existing data can be handled different ways depending on the DB.

Comment: You'll want to make a separate loop.  You can use a Tuple<String, String, String, String>.  You create an empty list of them.  Then loop through the grid and add records to the list.  In there, you can check if the tuple record already exists in the list you are adding to.  The benefit of using Tuple rather than a custom object is that it will handle all the list contains/equality functionality for you already.

Comment: I'm just trying new things, coz I'm trying to learn . ANw mate can you provide me sample code? just like on how to do it. Just my basis. Thanks mate

Comment: This looks crazy vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: If you build and configure a DataAdapter, you dont need to loop at all `myDA.Update(myDT)` is all you need.  It will send *all* the inserts, *all* the Updates and all the Deletes to the db for you.  if you are indeed learning, you need to do some research rather than guess how it is done.  There are hundreds and hundreds of posts here on various aspects of it

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn This is my own system, a stand alone who cares about injection? Security isnt my priority. I just want to check duplicate records. Please answer according to the question or else don't just comment mate. Can't you see I'm trying?

Comment: @Plutonix I see. I somewhat I have an idea now. Thanks mate. I'll do some research.

Comment: Its not ***just*** SQL injection - though since this is SO, such things are of grave concern.  There are all sorts of things that can go wrong with gluding bits of string together.  Syntax errors with a missing tick, data type mismatches, special characters (`Bob O'Brian`) as well as simply gruesome code.  A very very large portion of the ADO NET posts here carry the solution to *always use SQL Parameters*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if record exists, u can actually check the database's specific column to see if the column has any rows containing the same record u are trying to insert..TO do this,first u need to check the database for duplicates and then insert new data if no duplicates exist.A full example might look like this :

```
 Dim cmd as new SqlCommand("Select * from TABLENAME([column names-remove brackets if required])values(@value1)",con)
 cmd.parametres.AddWithValue("@value1",Firstname.Text)
 Dim dr as new SqlDataReader=cmd.Executereader

 If dr.hasRows  Then      'This checks if any duplicates exist
 Msgbox("Duplicates Found")
Else
 Dim cmd as new SqlCommand("Inserting data query here",con)

 cmd.parametres.Add("@value1",SqlDbtype.Varchar).value=Firstame.Text
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
```

Here i've assumed u r using Sql Server, make necessary changes to the code

Comment: or just use `if not exists(select <column name> from <table> where <column name> = <value>) begin insert.... end`

Comment: does the same thing bro, but thanks for mentioning @F0r3v3r-A-N00b , so, should i add it to my answer ? u'ld have to remove your comment then

Comment: It saves trips to the server

Comment: Or pass a table-valued parameter to sql server and do away with the loop.